# Removing the Underscore in Heading

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the header to just not have underscore but space.

Instead of

```
Select  primary_id as id_number
from x
```

I want

```
Select primary_id as 'id number'
from x
```

Is that possible in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Try it.

More to the point, why would you want to? It doesn't matter much what the database column is called; presumably you aren't displaying the column name directly on the screen anywhere. The column headings you show on-screen should be human-friendly, while the database column names should be computer-friendly. In general, spaces tend to get in the way for the computers: they have to be encoded specially in URLs, they don't work in variable names, etc.